# SQL count returns a bad result

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to know the number of subcommands that meet certain conditions.

I want to count the number of instances where order_payment_id is ‘3' and whose status is shipped, but I am having a hard time getting the SQL count function to work.

— I have this first query to display the results in a table :

```
SELECT
    order_id, order_number, lh45p_users.name, lh45p_hikamarket_vendor.vendor_name, order_status, order_created, order_full_price, order_payment_id
FROM
    lh45p_hikashop_order
INNER JOIN
    lh45p_hikamarket_vendor ON lh45p_hikashop_order.order_vendor_id = lh45p_hikamarket_vendor.vendor_id
INNER JOIN
    lh45p_hikashop_user ON lh45p_hikashop_order.order_user_id = lh45p_hikashop_user.user_id
INNER JOIN
    lh45p_users ON lh45p_hikashop_user.user_cms_id = lh45p_users.id
WHERE
    order_status = 'shipped' AND order_payment_id = '3'
ORDER BY
    lh45p_hikashop_order.order_created ASC
```

— Here is the table displayed (I changed some values to ensure confidentiality) :

```
ID | N° de commande | Client | Vendeur | Statut | Date | Prix |
:---: | :---: | :---: | :---: | :---: | :---: | :---: |
111 | 2016-0110 | Client 1 | Vendeur 1 | shipped | 29-02-2016 | 94.8 |
116 | 2016-0115 | Client 2 | Vendeur 2 | shipped | 11-03-2016 | 94.8 |
131 | 2016-0130 | Client 3 | Vendeur 3 | shipped | 10-04-2016 | 94.2 |
136 | 2016-0135 | Client 4 | Vendeur 4 | shipped | 16-06-2016 | 219.6 |
157 | 2016-0156 | Client 5 | Vendeur 5 | shipped | 04-08-2016 | 94.2 |
162 | 2016-0161 | Client 6 | Vendeur 6 | shipped | 09-08-2016 | 108 |
178 | 2016-0177 | Client 7 | Vendeur 7 | shipped | 10-09-2016 | 31.2 |
193 | 2016-0192 | Client 8 | Vendeur 8 | shipped | 18-10-2016 | 31.5 |
194 | 2016-0192 | Client 9 | Vendeur 9 |shipped | 18-10-2016 | 55.4 |
196 | 2016-0195 | Client 10 | Vendeur 10 | shipped | 02-11-2016 | 57.1 |
```

— Here is the query to count the number of instances (I used the same simplified query without the joins) :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(order_id) AS nb_order
FROM
    lh45p_hikashop_order
WHERE
    order_payment_id = '3' AND order_status = 'shipped'
```

When I use this query in phpMyAdmin, I find a result of 17 when it should return 10. The table lh45p_hikashop_order in phpMyAdmin contains 24 rows. And when I display the result in Joomla, I find 21.

I consulted other questions already posted on **stackoverflow** on this subject.

Thanks in advance

---

**(EDIT) SOLUTION :**

I managed to correct my error, I kept the joins as specified by RiggsFolly.

Here is the query that works:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(order_id) AS nb_order
FROM
    lh45p_hikashop_order
INNER JOIN
    lh81p_hikamarket_vendor ON lh45p_hikashop_order.order_vendor_id = lh45p_hikamarket_vendor.vendor_id
INNER JOIN
    lh45p_hikashop_user ON lh45p_hikashop_order.order_user_id = lh45p_hikashop_user.user_id
INNER JOIN
    lh45p_users ON lh45p_hikashop_user.user_cms_id = lh45p_users.id
WHERE
    order_status = 'shipped' AND order_payment_id = '3'
ORDER BY
    lh45p_hikashop_order.order_created ASC
```

Thanks again

Comment: Use exectly the same query with all the joins, just change the `SELECT COUNT(order_id) AS nb_order` What count do you get then???

Comment: Probably the inner joins eliminated some of the records from lh45p_hikashop_order from the resultset. You are comparing apples with pears if you overlook the inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

Inner join returns only matched rows.
Apparently there are some rows in your tables do not have matches in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
    `Select Count(*) As InstanceCount` ....?

without changing the other parts?

Comment: And check if any inner joins return null